# Yii and PHPUnit Autoloaders conflict

Tags: php, yii, phpunit, autoloader, spl-autoload-register

This question is related to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932563/phpunit-autoloading-classes) I had, but I learned a bit more now, and that question became too messy, so I start a new question here.

I am trying to use Yii and PHPUnit at the same time, and try to get the Autoloading working. I found an Autoloader [here](http://pastebin.com/ZDE4WQ59) that I am using for PHPUnit. I read [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/nl/extension.integration#using-3rd-party-autoloaders) that I should register the Yii autoloader last.

With the following bootstrap file:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/../tests/AutoLoader.php');
Toolbox\Testing\AutoLoader::registerDirectory(__DIR__.'/../protected');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/yii.php');
print_r(spl_autoload_functions());
?>
```

I see that the autoloaders are in place in the right order:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Toolbox\Testing\AutoLoader
        [1] => loadClass
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => YiiBase
        [1] => autoload
    )
```

However, I still can't import the class I need. It goes wrong in YiiBase in the function `autoload` in the line `include($className.'.php');`, which tries to include a class name without a path attached to it.

1. Why does Yii try to load a class without a full path to the file needed?
2. How can I make this combination to work?

Comment: What is the path of the file you are trying to include? Is it PSR-4 compliant (Yii autoloader is PSR-4 compatible only). [PSR-4 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md)

Comment: I solved it by adding the correct `includePaths` in the `config/main.php` file.